# How to monitor SOLR

Tags: monitoring, solr

We have SOLR running on a windows platform in our development environment, and on a Linq platform for production.  We would like to monitor the SOLR index.  We currently have Microsoft MOM (I think this has been renamed in the new version?) for monitoring our environment, it would be great if the monitoring solution could integrate with MOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been finding that [LucidGaze](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Downloads/LucidGaze-for-Solr) has been very helpful in monitoring Solr. It's handy to know what the requests/second and ms/request are when trying to determine what part of our deployment is lagging behind. I don't believe it integrates with MOM, not much that I've worked with except other Microsoft products due but that's par for the course.